# Capture number between two whitespaces (RegEx)

Tags: regex, extract, whitespace

I have the following data:

```
SOMEDATA .test 01/45/12 2.50 THIS IS DATA
```

and I want to extract the number 2.50 out of this. I have managed to do this with the following RegEx:

```
(?<=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} )\d+.\d+
```

However that doesn't work for input like this:

```
SOMEDATA .test 01/45/12 2500 THIS IS DATA
```

In this case, I want to extract the number 2500.

I can't seem to figure out a regex rule for that. Is there a way to extract something between two spaces ? So extract the text/number after the date until the next whitespace ? All I know is that the date will always have the same format and there will always be a space after the text and then a space after the number I want to extract.

Can someone help me out on this ?

Comment: Does your line actually have the text `THIS IS DATA` ?

Comment: @SebastianProske that works perfectly. Thanks so much. Can you maybe explain what you are doing there with \d+(.\d+)?

Comment: @user2606751: See my comment to the current answer. The main point is that your regex is not "proper" as the dot is unescaped. You need to use it the way Dmitry shows, else you won't be able to match 1-digit values, like `SOMEDATA .test 01/45/12 2 THIS IS DATA`.

Comment: Or are you sure you posted the exact pattern you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Capture number between two whitespaces

A whitespace is matched with `\s`, and non-whitespace with `\S`.

So, what you can use is:

```
\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} +(\S+)
                      ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xG5xS1/2)

The 1+ non-whitespace symbols are captured into Group 1.

If - for some reason - you need to only get the value as a whole match, use your lookbehind approach:

```
(?<=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} )\S+
```

Or - if you are using PCRE - you may leverage the match reset operator `\K`:

```
\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} +\K\S+
                     ^^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/xG5xS1/3)

**NOTE**: the `\K` and a capture group approaches allow 1 or more spaces after the date and are thus more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the fractal part optional:

```
(?<=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} )\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jH3pU7/1

**Update following clarifications in comments:**

To match anything (but space) surrounded by spaces and prepended by date use:

```
(?<=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} )\S+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jH3pU7/3

Comment: The main point is that OP has an unescaped `.` that matches any symbol but a newline. No need to use that optional group if [`(?<=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} )\d+.\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/jH3pU7/2) is used. However, surely the dot must be escaped and an optional group used. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can we find a solution which extracts everything after the date until the next whitespace ? regardless of what's in the text dot or comma or anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

I see some people helped you already, but if you would want an alternative working one for some reason, here's what works too :)

```
.+ \d+\/\d+\/\d+ (\d+[\.\d]*)
```

So the .+ matches anything plus the first space
then the \d+/\d+/\d+ is the date parsing plus a space
the capturing group is the number, as you can see I made the last part optional, so both floating point values and normal values can be matched. Hope this helped!

Proof: https://regex101.com/r/fY3nJ2/1

Answer (score 1):

Rather than capture, you can make your entire match be the target text by using a look behind:

```
(?<=\d\d(\/\d\d){2} )\S+
```

This matches the first series of non-whitespace that follows a "date like" part.

Note also the reduction in the length of the "date like" pattern. You may consider using this part of the regex in whatever solution you use.